# Explanation of the SQL REVERT Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax

I have been looking into the syntax REVERT, I have read the microsoft documentation regarding this however as much as it shows how to use it, i do not believe it properly explains what *exactly* it does and how to use it.

Can anyone explain this syntax to me and perhaps a better example of how/why you would use it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/revert-transact-sql and tthis: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql and are still no happy with the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Stored Procedure which calls another Stored Procedure. If you want to allow the user to have execute rights on the first SP, but not on the SP inside, you can use EXECUTE AS before calling the inner SP. Because EXECUTE AS will persist during the rest of the session, you can call REVERT to return to the original user scheme.

Comment: Ah ok i think that makes sense. Just to be clear this is not a syntax you would use to ROLLBACK a previously committed transaction, or is there some use for REVERT in this situation?

Comment: Indeed, REVERT and ROLLBACK are two completely different statements.